# Why doesn't my app show the downloaded images in ImageView and the downloaded text in Button?

Tags: android, download

Here's the code of my test app "Guess the Pokémon", which takes names of the first 151 Pokémon and their relative pictures from a website, and put them into an ImageView and 4 Buttons. The user has to guess which Pokémon it is, every turn. It is a test app in order to learn to download things from Internet.

As you can understand by the title of this question, when I run the app the ImageView does not get any Image from the URL and the Buttons any Text. But if I press some Buttons, I get a "correct" or "wrong" Toast.
I've asked the android.permission.INTERNET in the Manifest.
What should I do? It seems perfect to me.

Thank you for your consideration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/downloadedImage"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:padding="100dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:tag="0"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:tag="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:tag="2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:tag="3"/>

</GridLayout>






import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> pokedex;
    ArrayList<String> imagePokedex;
    int random;
    ImageView downloadedImage;
    int correctAnswerPosition;
    String[] answers = new String[4];
    GridLayout gridLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        pokedex = new ArrayList<String>();
        imagePokedex = new ArrayList<String>();
        downloadedImage = findViewById(R.id.downloadedImage);

        String result;
        PokemonNamesDownloader pokemonNamesDownloader = new PokemonNamesDownloader();
        try {
            result = pokemonNamesDownloader.execute("https://www.pokemonmillennium.net/videogiochi/pokemon-go/pokedex-di-prima-generazione/").get();
            // Pokemon Names
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/>#[0-9][0-9][0-9](.*?)</td>");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

            while (m.find()) {
                pokedex.add(m.group(1));
            }

            //Pokemon Images
            p = Pattern.compile("\"aligncenter\" src=\"(.*?)\" />#");
            m = p.matcher(result);

            while (m.find()) {
                imagePokedex.add(m.group(1));
            }
            System.out.println(imagePokedex.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                ((Button) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText(risposte[i]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setImagesAndButtons();

        Button button0, button1, button2, button3;
        button0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(v);
            }
        });
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(v);
            }
        });
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(v);
            }
        });
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view) {
        if ((view).getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(correctAnswerPosition))) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong! The correct answer was" +pokedex.get(random), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        setImageAndButtons();
    }

    public void setImageAndButtons() {
        
        Bitmap myBitmap=null;
        ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();

        random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*152);
        try {
            myBitmap = imageDownloader.execute(imagePokedex.get(random)).get();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        downloadedImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        //set Buttons
        correctAnswerPosition = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            if (i==correctAnswerPosition) {
                answers[i] = pokedex.get(random);
            } else {
                int wrongAnswerPosition = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *152);
                while (pokedex.get(wrongAnswerPosition).equals(pokedex.get(random))) {
                    wrongAnswerPosition = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *152);
                }
                answers[i] = pokedex.get(wrongAnswerPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return myBitmap;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
    public class PokemonNamesDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String result="";

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your layout file?

Comment: ((Button) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText(risposte[i]);

What is riposte here?

Comment: I'm italian, so I use in my code italian names, "risposte[]" was the array "answers[]" which I forgot to translate in my question! sorry

Comment: Added the layout xml file!